# Can't properly add a vertial line to a table

Tags: tables

I'm trying to add a vertical line to the left-most column of the table with code below.

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{8pt}
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{GRU} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{GRU + ELMo} \\\cline{2-3}
 acurácia & $0.767700$ & $0.776100$ \\\cline{2-3}
 precisão & $0.770971$ & $0.787500$ \\\cline{2-3}
 f-\textit{measure} & $0.769034$ & $0.780582$ \\\cline{2-3}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This code generates this table:

[image]

I wanted it to look like this:

[image]

How can I get this to work?

Comment: well add the line to the tabular preamble: `{c|c|c|c|}`.

Comment: In the preamle you define 4 columns, but in the table you need just 3. Try: `c|c|c|`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the below meets your requirement:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{GRU} &
          \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\mathrm{GRU} + \mathrm{ELMo}$} \\
\cline{2-3}
 acurácia & $0.767700$ & $0.776100$ \\
\cline{2-3}
 precisão & $0.770971$ & $0.787500$ \\
\cline{2-3}
 f-\textit{measure} & $0.769034$ & $0.780582$ \\
\cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:results-measures}Comparativo das métricas obtidas nos experimentos realizados.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi @heniotierra and welcome to TeX-SE. When asking a question, please inform a MWE that reproduces your issue.

And you should use `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` or `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to correct handles accents and other special characters (We from Brazil must pay attention at this) and as your are writing in Portuguese, use `\usepackage[brazil]{babel}` to correct handle table and figure captions.
Also pay attention to norms, sometimes the captions must be above the object (table or figure), sometimes below. I let comment the placement of a "below caption".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Comparativo}
\label{tab:results-measures}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{8pt}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{GRU} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{GRU + ELMo} \\
    \cline{2-3}
          acurácia       &       $0.767700$        &           $0.776100$           \\
    \cline{2-3}
          precisão       &       $0.770971$        &           $0.787500$           \\
    \cline{2-3}
     f-\textit{measure}  &       $0.769034$        &           $0.780582$           \\
    \cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}
%\caption{Comparativo Below}
%\label{tab:results-measures}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the tips, man! :)

Comment: You are welcome @hienotierra. I know sometimes it is a little bit difficult to find some simple but fundamental advice of specific language related issues.